# JIRA JQL - Find all subtasks that are open where the parent is closed

Tags: jira, jql

I have to do a little sub-task clean-up and wondering if there is an easier solution to do this using JQL.

Basically i want to find all sub-tasks that are not closed where the parent of that sub-task is closed. Is this possible?

I have tried to google the problem but the majority of the solutions require installation of a plugin which unfortunately i am not able to. Is there an alternative?

My attempt so far:

```
(project = MYPROJECT        
         AND issuetype = Sub-task 
         AND status in (Open, "In Progress", Reopened, Resolved)
         AND issue in parent(project in ("MYPROJECT")  and status = Closed)
        )
```

But there is no parent function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible with JQL out of the box. But there's a [free plugin that allows this](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner). 
See examples listed [here](https://jamieechlin.atlassian.net/wiki/display/GRV/Scripted+JQL+Functions).

The JQL you're looking for should be like this:

`type = sub-task and status = Open and issueFunction in subtasksOf("status = closed")`

Comment: Thanks - I dont have access to add new plugins so that is not possible

Comment: It not free anymore. I suggest https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.atlassian.jira.copy-to-subtask-plugin/server/overview

Also i feel sad that we bought half-ready product. It's very rude.

Answer (score -1):

You can use below JQL to trace subtasks of a change request
**project = CLI AND issuetype = "Change Request" AND status = Completed AND issue in subtask("status != Done")**

Here You can change your project to multiple project e.g.
**project in ("proj1","proj1") AND issuetype = "Change Request" AND status = Completed AND issue in subtask("status != Done")**

Comment: Results in message "Unable to find JQL function 'subtask(status != Done)'."

Comment: Downvoted until more context is given because this query doesn't work in my current Jira setup. A quick Google search seems to indicated that a "JQL Tricks Plugin" (for cloud) exists, but no way to be sure.